# Job parameterization in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins

I want one job pass param to another job. The problem is that I want one job obtain parameter after execution shell command.

[image: jenkins]

Any ideas how to manage it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into EnvInject Plugin - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin
You can use it to load parameters from a file (which can be created by your shell step). You may than use the loaded variable to trigger the next job / step.